# joomla different CSS in multicategories

Tags: css, joomla

I have a joomla site, but I have a problem with the categories.
a particular category have a different appearance.

when I comparate the html, this category don't have some div/class as `.art-postcontent`, etc.

why some categories don't have same div?

#### EDIT

if I change the item order, I fix the CSS problem, but I need `most recent first`

[image: ss]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was not with the category, the problem was with a `<div>` in one article of this category .

I remove this div's and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla is a complex CMS, capable of producing different generated HTML based on a large number of things (components, modules, plugins, etc.).

If you're not familiar with PHP, your best bet is to look through any modules/components/plugins, articles, etc from the admin interface that may be affecting the category you're curious about and see if anything is causing the conflict.

If you don't spot it there, then just start disabling modules/components/plugins one by one until the culprit reveals itself.